# Fix Garage Door Bracket

Tags: garage, construction, garage-door-opener

My garage door bracket is starting to pull out from the top panel of the door.  Some friends of mine have pointed me to a opener reinforcement like the one linked below but others have suggested mounting a steel plate to the door and using the existing bracket.  I am concerned that the Home Depot reinforcement wouldn't stand the test of time.  Does anyone have any experience with either of these methods?

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Clopay-21-in-Opener-Reinforcement-Bracket-Kit-4125479/100069364

[image][image]

Comment: Are the bolts actually coming loose? Is the structural member under the skin of the door flexing or is it simply just the interior skin of the door which is cracking? You may not need any reinforcement. My opener is attached to the vertical steel member in the steel door and doesn't need extra reinforcement. What is the material and construction of your door?

Comment: Is there a horizontal steel beam at the top of the door? My door has only two horizontal beams--one at the top and one at the bottom. The top of  my door fits against the inside face of the header. Yours appears to fit under the header. Does the door rub against the header when it opens or closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve, from the looks of the picture it appears as though part of the bracket is fastened to wafer board. In this cas it may pay you to put a steel plate (1/8" should suffice) under the bracket for support. Hover I do suggest doing it to both sides, since it is a matter of time before the other one loosens. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by both sides?

Comment: Don't you have a bracket on the other side of the door? Or is this on the center one?

Comment: No, this is for the center bracket that is attached to the door arm/motor unit.  The center part of the second image I just added

Comment: Ok, just install a plate that extends a inch or more on on all sides of the bracket, and you'll be good to go. I'd also recommend using pan head screws agaist the plate. You may need to drill holes in the plate if you can;t find a suitable prefabbed one.